# Java XML file editing

Tags: java, xml, automation, dataset

does someone know how I could change the inner values of this XML sample in java?

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>

<dataSet xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <name>test</name>
  <type>default-type</type>
  <recordSets>
    <recordSet>
      <name>USER_Props</name>
      <fields>
        <field>
          <name>ID</name>
          <type>string</type>
        </field>
        <field>
          <name>NAME</name>
          <type>string</type>
        </field>
        <field>
          <name>LANGUAGE</name>
          <type>string</type>
        </field>
      </fields>
      <records>
        <record>
          <values>
            <element>580710699</element>
            <element>John Doe</element>
            <element>spanish</element>
          </values>
        </record>
      </records>
    </recordSet>
    <recordSet>
      <name>USER_special_Props</name>
      <fields>
        <field>
          <name>Haircolor</name>
          <type>string</type>
        </field>
        <field>
          <name>Eyecolor</name>
          <type>string</type>
        </field>
        <field>
          <name>HasPet</name>
          <type>bool</type>
        </field>
      </fields>
      <records>
        <record>
          <values>
            <element>gray</element>
            <element>blue</element>
            <element>false</element>
          </values>
        </record>
      </records>
    </recordSet>
  </recordSets>
</dataSet>
```

I already tried it with xpath, but could not really gain what I wanted.

I would like to have a method like this: changeValue(fieldName, recordValueElement) --> return newValue

and maybe a method like this: checkIfFieldExists(fieldName)

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score -1):

There is a library called **JAXB**. When i worked with XML files, it did a quite good job for me.

If you are looking for a quick example: https://www.mkyong.com/java/jaxb-hello-world-example/